# IPython interpreter for conda environments on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, elpy, ipython

I am using Anaconda3 for managing my environments and the IPython interpreter in Emacs. When activating an environment with `pyvenv-activate` the completion in the IPython interpreter is not working and shows the following warning:

`c:\[user]\Anaconda3\envs\[environment]\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:841: UserWarning: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.`

Although the IPython interpreter is installed in the conda environment that I load and the `elpy-config` reads:

```
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: [environment] (c:/[user]/Anaconda3/envs/[environment]/)
Interactive Python: ipython 8.2.0 (c:/[user]/Anaconda3/envs/[environment]/Scripts/ipython.exe)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (c:/[user]/Anaconda3/envs)
 Python...........: python 3.9.7 (c:/[user]/Anaconda3/envs/[environment]/python.exe)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.1
 Autopep8.........: Not found (1.6.0 available)
 Yapf.............: Not found (0.32.0 available)
 Black............: Not found (22.3.0 available)
Syntax checker....: flake8.exe (c:/[user]/Anaconda3/Scripts/flake8.exe)
```

In the init.el I have:

```
(elpy-enable)
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python"
     python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
     python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```

I have looked at the following references, but neither of them worked:

- https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1673
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175916/emacs-and-conda-workaround

**Edit:**
The same settings work on Ubuntu but not with Windows 10.